# Is this language regular or not regular {(a* union b)a } intersection {a*b*} is a regular language

Tags: regular-expressions

Is {(a* ∪ b)b } intersection {a* b* } a regular language?

Comment: Isn't the language $a^*b\cup bb$?

Comment: As @xskxzr shows, you can easily compute the set of strings in the intersection, but note that regular languages are closed under intersection, so the answer is yes, immediately.

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Your question is a basic one. Since you [did 
not include much of an attempt to solve it on your own](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/594), we have little to
work with. Let me direct you towards our 
[reference questions](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/599)
which cover your problem in detail.
Please work through the related questions listed there and try to solve your 
problem again.  In the future include your attempts along with the specific 
problems you encountered.